# How to create a new Spatialite database in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector, spatialite

I've been trying to create a new spatialite database within QGIS 1.8 (SpatiaLite Version 3.0.1; QSpatialite 6.0.3) and keep getting this error: "The SQL query seems to be invalid.
no such table: views_geometry_columns" and then "This DataBase seems to be a valid SQLite DataBase but not a valid SpatiaLite One, Would you like QSpatiaLite to automatically transform it to SpatiaLite (information won't be lost) ?" and after "Yes" comes "Unable to convert Database to SpatiaLite".

What am I doing wrong? There was no problems with old version (QGIS 1.7.4 and QSpatialite 5.0.3).

Please advise regarding creating a new Spatialite database.

---

Spatialite-gui did the trick. You just have to have right SRID.
Here is the SRID list
http://drupalcode.org/project/geo.git/blob/ee3f75649e4b01dfd27d8e35b222a2b51c93d706:/srid.inc

Comment: Can you explain the steps you are taking to get this error message?

Comment: You get this error, if you save a layer with "Save as...". Best way is Layer-> Add new Layer -> New spatialite layer, and then the three points to create a new database.

Comment: 0down vote accept
 


Spatialite-gui did the trick. You just have to have right SRID. Here is the SRID list http://drupalcode.org/project/geo.git/blob/ee3f75649e4b01dfd27d8e35b222a2b51c93d706:/srid.inc

Thank you all for your effort and time!

Comment: I have spatialite 2.0.1, qgis 1.8.0 and qspatialite 6.0.7 and I still have the problem. Somebody knows a solution to fixe the bug ?

Answer (score 6):

Qspatialite is incompatible with spatialite 3 (see http://code.google.com/p/qspatialite/issues/detail?id=6) and AFAIK DB Manager is incompatible too. Use spatialite-gui (https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/spatialite_gui/index) to manage your database and ogr2ogr to add or export layers. Or install spatialite 2.x.

Answer (score 4):

This is a known bug.
Now fixed in QSpatiaLite v 6.0.6

RIVIERE Romain
QSpatiaLite Developer

Answer (score 2):

I think there are problems with QSpatialite and more recent versions of QGIS. If you have spatialite-gui this is good for creating Spatialite DBs and populating them. You could try running "spatialite_gui" from a terminal (without the quotation marks) to see if you have it installed. I can't remember if my spatialite-gui came with QGIS or whether I installed it separately, sorry.

Comment: spatialite-gui is available [here](https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/index.html). Agreed - I find it much much easier to work with than the QGIS interface to spatialite.